# Inversion of subject and verb

Tags: grammar

Question one:
**Are the following sentences correct? And why?** 
Statement A:
**After storms is not necessarily a bright sky.** (I think it will be correct only by inserting there between storms and is)

It seems correct to say:
 Statement B:
**After storm comes a bright sky.** 
( to sound more idiomatic, I believe the subject and object should be reversed into: a bright sky comes after storm)

If only statement B is the correct one, this makes a huge difference between copular verb *is* and *come*.

If my assumption is not all nonsense, what's the reason beneath this difference? And what the grammar point I should seek references from? Thanks.

**Question 2:**
Which one is correct?

1. Not always rainbow will follow the rain.
2. Not always will rainbow follow the rain.
3. It is not always that rainbow will follow the rain.
4. Not always there is rainbow following the rain.
5. Not always is there rainbow following the rain.

I'd say among the 5 sentences above, sentences 2, 3, and 5 are rather correct. 
And if indeed the rest two are wrongly constructed sentences, why? Thanks.

Comment: Not a single one of the sentences above is grammatically correct, either before or after the changes you suggest.

Comment: @DJClayworth my suggested version, if it is  wrong, the problem with it is less jarring to me. Can you kindly state the reasons for why they are wrong? And thanks for letting me know none of them are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately proofreading is off topic here. However in most cases it is a missing article.

Comment: a bright sky comes after the storm.

Comment: So the grammar point is on articles?